# Remove border from geom_rect using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = bayes, aes(x = Order, y = value, fill=key, color=key)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = Order, xmax = dplyr::lead(Order), ymin= -Inf, ymax =Inf, colour=Summary), 
            alpha=0.1) +
  geom_line(size=0.5) + 
  geom_point() + 
  xlab("Bayesian combination") +
  ylab("Bayesian probability") +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  ylim(0,1) + 
  xlim(1,126)
```

Just for you to know my data structure:

```
> str(bayes)
'data.frame':   252 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Summary    : chr  "1 vs. 6" "1 vs. 6" "1 vs. 6" "1 vs. 6" ...
 $ Combination: chr  "I1 if I2CP3P4M1M2" "I2 if I1CP3P4M1M2" "C if I1I2P3P4M1M2" "P3 if I1I2CP4M1M2" ...
 $ Order      : int  126 125 124 123 122 121 120 119 118 117 ...
 $ key        : chr  "Lower_XVIII_UBU" "Lower_XVIII_UBU" "Lower_XVIII_UBU" "Lower_XVIII_UBU" ...
 $ value      : num  1 0.35 0.93 0.73 0.95 0.32 0.88 0.13 0.93 0.84 ...
```

My problem is that I cannot remove the outlines and borders from the geom_rect objects, making the figure unintelligible.

[image]

As you can see, I have 5 groups represented by five colors. However, within them there are plenty subrectangles each with their own border. I would like to remove all borders in the chart, so, where is the problem in the code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Example from the docs:

```
df <- data.frame(
    x = rep(c(2, 5, 7, 9, 12), 2),
    y = rep(c(1, 2), each = 5),
    z = factor(rep(1:5, each = 2)),
    w = rep(diff(c(0, 4, 6, 8, 10, 14)), 2)
)
```

You are doing this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(xmin = x - w / 2, xmax = x + w / 2, ymin = y, ymax = y + 1, fill = z)) +
    geom_rect(aes(color = z), alpha = 0.1)
```

[image]

The problem is that the `alpha` is only applied to the `fill`, and not to the border (set with `color`). The solution is to remove the border entirely by *setting* (not mapping) `color` to `NA`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(xmin = x - w / 2, xmax = x + w / 2, ymin = y, ymax = y + 1, fill = z)) +
    geom_rect(color = NA, alpha = 0.3)
```

[image]