# Line graph in ggplot2 with some categorical variables and shading

Tags: r, ggplot2

First, my apologies because I've been trying to solve this issue by sectioning it in small parts (see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343911/remove-border-from-geom-rect-using-ggplot2/50344183#50344183), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50339909/shade-background-of-a-ggplot-chart-using-geom-rect-with-categorical-variables/50340204#50340204), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50334597/keeping-the-original-order-of-a-qualitative-variable-used-as-x-in-a-ggplot-chart/50335915#50335915)). However, I am totally stuck when merging all of them. In order to replicate it and ease reproducibility, you can [download the original data here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ulW1xbf2luzgqFK_OlAWTI2dvoUYWGw1/view?usp=sharing).

Once you load them in R, this is the structure:

```
> str(data_example2)
'data.frame':   252 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Groups  : Factor w/ 6 levels "Group1","Group2",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 ...
 $ Y_values: Factor w/ 126 levels "C if I1I2P3P4M1M2",..: 63 95 1 115 123 112 114 48 17 67 ...
 $ Units   : Factor w/ 2 levels "Uni1","Uni2": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ X_value : num  1 0.35 0.93 0.73 0.95 0.32 0.88 0.13 0.93 0.84 ...
```

So, what do I want? I would like to build a line chart in ggplot2 using these conditions:

- X axis represents variable `X_value`.
- Y axis represents variable `Y_value`. As you can see in variable `Units`, we have two groups (`Uni1` and `Uni2`), each composed by 126 observations. More importantly, these 126 observations in each Unit is composed by 126 factors. It is very important **to keep the order** of these `Y_values`, so that in the line graph the top left Y value should be `I1 if I2CP3P4M1M2` and the bottom left should be `I1I2CP3 if P4M1M2`
- I would like to trace two lines, on for `Uni1`, and one for `Uni2`.
- I would like to shade the background using the factors represented in the variable `Groups`, maybe using `geom_rect()`, but without representing the outlines of the rectangles and keeping different colors for each of the 6 groups.

Final chart should be something like this but shading per `Groups`.
[image]

Comment: You might have made a few errors here. You said 2 groups `Uni1` and `Uni2` but your `str()` showed that you have 6 levels, not 2. You said 126 observations, but your `str()` showed 125 levels, not 126.

Comment: ohhh. Units is well formed by 2 groups, variable Groups is formed by 6. I am going to check Y_vales. Thanks

Comment: I updated the dataset to have 126 factors in the `Y_values` column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this can help, it's not perfect but can get you closer to what you need:

```r
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)

y_val_levels <- unique(df$Y_values)
```

#### Using `geom_ribbon`

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(Y_values, levels = y_val_levels, ordered = TRUE))) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, fill = Groups, group = Groups), alpha = .2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = X_value, color = Units, group = Units)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = X_value, color = Units)) +
  scale_x_discrete('Bayesian combination') +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 5))
```

[image]

#### Using `geom_rect`

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(Y_values, levels = y_val_levels, ordered = TRUE))) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.integer(factor(Y_values, levels = y_val_levels, ordered = TRUE)) - .5,
                xmax = as.integer(factor(Y_values, levels = y_val_levels, ordered = TRUE)) + .5,
                ymin = -Inf, 
                ymax = Inf, 
                fill = Groups, group = Groups), alpha = .2) +
  geom_line(aes(y = X_value, color = Units, group = Units)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = X_value, color = Units)) +
  scale_x_discrete('Bayesian combination') +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 5))
```

[image]

(Note that the darker slice is due to a repeated value in `Y_values`)

Created on 2018-05-15 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Wow!!! I prefer the ribbon option rather than the rect. Ona last thing, how can I invert Y axis?

Comment: any idea how to upside down the Y axis?

Comment: An idea might be `aes(x = forcats::fct_rev(factor(Y_values, levels = y_val_levels, ordered = TRUE)))`, I'm sure there are simpler methods