# geom_rect borders with PDF output

Tags: r, ggplot2, pdf

this is a similar question as was asked here:
[Remove border from geom_rect using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343911/remove-border-from-geom-rect-using-ggplot2)

But the solution does not work when saving as a .pdf

```
df <- data.frame(
    x = rep(c(2, 5, 7, 9, 12), 2),
    y = rep(c(1, 2), each = 5),
    z = factor(rep(1:5, each = 2)),
    w = rep(diff(c(0, 4, 6, 8, 10, 14)), 2)
)

pdf('tmp.pdf')
ggplot(df, aes(xmin = x - w / 2, xmax = x + w / 2, ymin = y, ymax = y + 1, fill = z)) +
    geom_rect(color = NA, alpha = 0.3) +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
           panel.grid.minor = element_blank())

dev.off()
```

produces a pdf with borders around the rect. See image below. How can I save this as a pdf without these borders?

[image]

By borders, I mean the darker lines between the colors. Here is a version of the plot without the borders (not printed to a pdf).

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by *"borders around the rect"*? If you mean the space between the axis and the rectangles then try with `+ coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)` to remove the default expansion of the scales.

Comment: @stefan please see edits above.

Comment: Thx Jacob. Now I see what you mean and can confirm that this happens only when exporting to pdf. But unfortunately I have no clue how to fix that.

Comment: I think it's perhaps a display thing - viewing the pdf overlaps the semi-transparent boxes slightly and renders a tiny 'border'. Converting the pdf to svg has no border. Zooming in doesn't 'thicken' the border appearance. Taking off transparency makes any apparent border disappear. That would indicate the border isn't really "there". Not sure what the fix would be for displaying though.

Comment: unless the alpha parameter only applies to the fill and not the color parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot explain how to fix this. However, I have been struggling with this problem in the past and had been reading up on how to control the colour aesthetics, i.e. its [evaluation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_eval.html) in ggplot.

The results gets you closer to your desired `pdf output` - but you loose the on the png/html side.

The issue at hand is that the pdf printing seems to have another `grading` between the *color* and *fill* alpha.
The presented solution "manipulates" the grading to make it look (sort of) identical in pdf (but as said, this weight-grading does not produce the same in other outputs - now you will have the pesky borderlines there) :(.

Maybe others can improve the explanation of the answer?

You can "force" the evaluation of the (borderline) color aesthetic to be dependent on an aesthetics mapping, i.e. `fill = z`.

Setting the `alpha = 0.3` in the geom_rect() call/layer will give you the standard alpha level fill.
However, you can now point the borderline color to make use of the `fill-mapping` by assigning "another" value to it, once the fill is evaluated. For this you use the `after_scale()`, and in it you make the line-color dependent on `fill` and give it an `alpha`.

The example feels like there is a factor of 2 involved. It is not. If you zoom into the pdf, you will see that the colors are not a perfect match.
So given your color setting, you need to play around with the `after_scale(alpha(fill, <<adapt me to your liking>>)`.

```
df <- data.frame(
    x = rep(c(2, 5, 7, 9, 12), 2),
    y = rep(c(1, 2), each = 5),
    z = factor(rep(1:5, each = 2)),
    w = rep(diff(c(0, 4, 6, 8, 10, 14)), 2)
)
pdf('tmp.pdf')
ggplot(df, aes(xmin = x - w / 2, xmax = x + w / 2, ymin = y, ymax = y + 1, fill = z)) +
    geom_rect(aes(color = after_scale(alpha(fill, 0.15))) , alpha = 0.3) +
  
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
dev.off()
```

This yields as pdf output (which is "pretty close"):

[image]

In hindsight, your observation is certainly correct: the pdf printing does something to the parameters.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

While this does not provide a solution to include alpha in the pdf, it does provide an way to lighten the geom_rect colors without having those pesky border lines in the pdf.

```
library(prismatic)
df <- data.frame(
    x = rep(c(2, 5, 7, 9, 12), 2),
    y = rep(c(1, 2), each = 5),
    z = factor(rep(1:5, each = 2)),
    w = rep(diff(c(0, 4, 6, 8, 10, 14)), 2)
)
pdf('tmp.pdf')
ggplot(df, aes(xmin = x - w / 2, xmax = x + w / 2, ymin = y, ymax = y + 1, fill = color)) +
    geom_rect(aes(fill = stage(start = z,
                               after_scale = clr_lighten(fill, space = 'combined'))))+
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
dev.off()
```

[image]

Maybe someone can add to this a way to include alpha.