# How to remove the outline around geom_rect in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
mydat <- data.frame(mean = c(23, 24, 15, 27, 18, 19, 23, 20, 32),
                    lower = c(20, 19, 13, 15, 14, 18, 20, 17, 20),
                    upper = c(25, 29, 17, 39, 22, 20, 26, 23, 40),
                    class = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
                    domain = c("North", "North", "North", "West", "West", "West", "South", "South", "South"),
                    stripe = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1))
mydat$class <- as.factor(mydat$class)
mydat$domain <- as.factor(mydat$domain)
mydat$stripe <- as.factor(mydat$stripe)

colour_palette <- scales::hue_pal()(3)

p <- mydat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mean, y = fct_reorder(.f = class, .x = upper, .fun = max),
             color = fct_reorder(.f = domain, .x = upper, .fun = max),
             Group = fct_reorder(.f = domain, .x = upper, .fun = max),
             xmin = lower, xmax = upper)) +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + 
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = 0.5, ymax = 1.5, xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, 
                fill = stripe), alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = 2.5, ymax = 3.5, xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, 
                fill = stripe), alpha = 0.1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey", "transparent")) +
  theme_light(base_size = 18) + 
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("North" = colour_palette[1],
                                "South" = colour_palette[2],
                                "West" = colour_palette[3]),
                     name = "Domain") +
  guides(fill = "none")
p
```

[image]

Is there a way to remove the green border around `geom_rect()`? I tried the solution from here: [Remove border from geom_rect using ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50343911/remove-border-from-geom-rect-using-ggplot2) by setting `color = NA` in `geom_rect()` but it did not work as intended:

```
p <- mydat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mean, y = fct_reorder(.f = class, .x = upper, .fun = max),
             color = fct_reorder(.f = domain, .x = upper, .fun = max),
             Group = fct_reorder(.f = domain, .x = upper, .fun = max),
             xmin = lower, xmax = upper)) +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + 
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = 0.5, ymax = 1.5, xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, 
                fill = stripe, color = NA), alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = 2.5, ymax = 3.5, xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, 
                fill = stripe, color = NA), alpha = 0.1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey", "transparent")) +
  theme_light(base_size = 18) + 
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("North" = colour_palette[1],
                                "South" = colour_palette[2],
                                "West" = colour_palette[3]),
                     name = "Domain") +
  guides(fill = "none")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that, if you [take another look](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50344183/4145280) at the answer you linked to, you'll see that `color = NA` isn't within an `aes()`, whereas in your code it is. Put it outside of the `aes()`, and the border goes away:

```
mydat %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = mean, y = fct_reorder(.f = class, .x = upper, .fun = max),
             color = fct_reorder(.f = domain, .x = upper, .fun = max),
             Group = fct_reorder(.f = domain, .x = upper, .fun = max),
             xmin = lower, xmax = upper)) +
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.1, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) + 
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = 0.5, ymax = 1.5, xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, 
                fill = stripe), alpha = 0.1, color = NA) +
  geom_rect(aes(ymin = 2.5, ymax = 3.5, xmin = -Inf, xmax = Inf, 
                fill = stripe), alpha = 0.1, color = NA) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey", "transparent")) +
  theme_light(base_size = 18) + 
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("North" = colour_palette[1],
                                "South" = colour_palette[2],
                                "West" = colour_palette[3]),
                     name = "Domain") +
  guides(fill = "none")
```

Output:
[image: plot]